# When cloning a MySQL db, does the "current database" name need to be changed for the new website?

Tags: mysql

When doing a mysqldump of a MySQL database, it includes the following at the top of the .sql file:

```
Host: localhost    Database: myaccount_mydb
```

The cloned database will have a different name (myaccount_mynewdb), in this example. Does myaccount_mydb need to be renamed in the .sql file prior to it being loaded in the new name? Or does this command line take care of it:

```
mysql --one-database myaccount_mynewdb < myaccount_mydb.sql -p
```

Does the mysql command ignore *Database: myaccount_mydb* entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host and database line is inside a comment (line starts with '-- '), so the line will be ignored by the MySQL command-line tool. It is information only.